# Drizzle ORM use postgres serial type with start value

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm, drizzle, drizzle-orm

I started with Drizzle ORM, I'm creating first user.ts schema:

```
import { pgTable, serial } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";

export const users = pgTable("users", {
 id: serial("id").primaryKey(),
});
```

I stacked with having the start value of this sequence `users_id_seq` without having to modify the db directly

I tried to modify the generated sql file that generated by drizzle:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
"id" serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);
ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH 10000;
```

But when I run drizzle command `push:pg` only create table statement runs

Is there any workaround using Drizzle ORM directly ?

Comment: You are restarting the sequence, but you are not referencing it. Take a look here: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-serial/